# A UI view to send some input parameters to an Ads-script

Tags: google-ads-api, google-ads-script

Is there any UI view to send some input parameters to an Ads-script?

In the documentation I see it's only hard-coding inside the script?

[image]

Comment: Google Apps Script is not the same than Google Ads Script... I just created a tag for it.

Comment: @Rubén thanks, but since it's a new tag, it won't get traffic. right? Do you know the answer to my original question?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the answer. Apparently it can't use the HTML Service from Google Apps Script as it's not listed in the Script services in https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/

Comment: Have you already tried https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-scripts? The Google Ads Script support page refers user to that forum instead of Stack Overflow.